# AutobahnJS: Remote call to asyncronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, autobahn, crossbar, wamp-protocol

I'm trying to make a call over WAMP to a remote function. But I don't know how to write the called function if it has asynchronous behavior. In every example I've seen the remote function **returns** the result. How can this be done in an asynchronous manner where I would normally use a callback?

Example:
This is the registration of a function that would get the contents of a file asynchronously.

```
session.register('com.example.getFileContents', getFileContents).then(
    function (reg) {
        console.log("procedure getFileContents() registered");
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log("failed to register procedure: " + err);
    }
);
```

Here is how I would call that function remotely.

```
session.call('com.example.getFileContents', ["someFile.txt"]).then(
    function (res) {
        console.log("File Contents:", res);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log("Error getting file contents:", err);
    }
);
```

But here is the actual function that was registered.

```
function getFileContents(file) {
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, data) {

        // How do I return the data?
    });
}
```

How do I return the data from getFileContents so that it can be sent back over the WAMP connection? I know I could use readFileSync and return what it returns. But I'm specifically asking how to do this in an asynchronous manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this with promises. Here is how the function implemented with promises.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var when = require('when');

function getFileContents(file) {
    var d = when.defer();
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        d.resolve(data);
    });
    return d.promise;
}
```